# MySql problems connecting to another port

Tags: mysql, database, port

I have followed the following tutorial to set up my computer so that others can access MySql:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345343(v=sql.105).aspx

The port that I had set up was 49172. When I now try to connect to this database from the same computer by using host name as my IP address, port as 49172, username as root and password as root I get an error saying I cannot connect to the server with some checks such as check if MySql is running, check rights and check firewalls (10061).

Could someone please tell me I am getting this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resetting IPTables as it might cause blocked connections.

Use these:

iptables -F

iptables -X

iptables -t nat -F

iptables -t nat -X

iptables -t mangle -F

iptables -t mangle -X

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT

iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT

Comment: On a windows box?!?!?!